# Can a circle be specified by an arbitrary triangle when one of its sides and the angle opposite to it is known?

Tags: circles

Given an arbitrary triangle where one of its sides is $a$ and the angle opposite to it is $A$, is there a circle with a unique radius $r$ such that this triangle is inscribed within it?

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of a standard result in plane geometry. If nobody else explains in an answer, I’ll do that.

Comment: The nearly universal convention for triangles is to use $r$ for the radius of the inscribed circle and $R$ for the radius of the circumcircle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: this is the *inscribed angle theorem*. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extended version of the sine rule to compute the radius of the circle $$\frac a{\sin A}=\frac b{\sin B}=\frac c{\sin C}=2R$$ where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle - this gives you $R$ in terms of the length of a side and the sine of the opposite angle, and that is the information you have to hand.

---

On the other hand, unless the angle given is a right-angle, there are two circles which conform to the criteria - if the given side is horizontal, one centre lies above the line and the other lies symmetrically below it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the triangle formed by connecting the centre of the circumcircle to the endpoints of the line segment of length $a$

The inscribed angle theorem tells you that the angle between the radii is $2A$